# about the my terminal appear this bash

Tags: terminal, python

```
Last login: Sat Jan 14 16:47:10 on ttys001
-bash: source /Users/liuyang/.bash_aliases: No such file or directory
-bash: source /Users/liuyang/.bash_aliases: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably was deleted, but reference from `.bashrc` is still exist.
Recreate this file with:

```
touch /Users/liuyang/.bash_aliases
```

then logout and relogin again

Comment: thanks so much   but oyur means logout the terminal or computer .

Comment: Logout/exit just from terminal and relogin